# Wordpress theme devepment - problem with enqueuing styles

Tags: wordpress, scss-mixins

this is my first attempt at creating a Wordpress theme so I probably did smething wrong. Anyway something strange happened, some of the styles disappeared (bootstrap) but instead there are some scss files - the url points at the main theme folder, but there are no such files in it. What I want to know is where these styles come from because I actually want to keep tose styles as a base for my theme [a screenshot from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojdXG.png)

Comment: When I see scss files in the console, it's usually because I have a sourcemap file. [It's quite useful](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sass-source-maps-chrome-magic), because your console will point you to the location of your style declaration in your scss files. If that's what is confusing you is hard to say with this little information.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, I noticed that I accidentally imported the whole styles directory instead of a single stylesheet in functions.php so wordpress must have found the map files that were there